# A button element that contains an icon that should change state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that contains an icon as well as text. When you toggle the button the icon and text both change. Easy enough, right?

But what container do I use for the icon? A DIV is the logical choice because I can swap states (that have different icons very easily), but  a DIV inside a button is semantically invalid HTML.

I could try an IMG tag but they need a SRC attribute defined and you can't do that in CSS.

And I don't want to use a SPAN with a display:block because I don't like that either.

Here's my button with a DIV as the container:

```
<button>

    <div id="mute" />

    Mute

</button>
```

And here's the CSS for the Mute and Un-mute states:

```
#mute {
    background: url(../images/mute_rest.svg) no-repeat;
    height:45px; 
    width:45px; 
}

#mute.unmute {
    background: url(../images/mute.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

In the program flow I can easily add/remove the "unmute" class thereby getting exactly what I want. But it's invalid HTML.

What alternative is there?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: There's no error. But the W3C validator says having a button inside a div is invalid html.

Comment: You could use a pseudo element like `:before`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why don't you like modifying the behaviour of a `span` to `inline-block` as all that is part of the magic of CSS, adapting it to your needs if the default behaviour isn't enough.

In any case, Bootstrap 2 would use an `<i>` element to designate icons, which given a width, height, and a background image would do just fine, and that's technically a tag to display italics, so I can't see why that would be invalid HTML inside a button, even according to the W3C validator.

An example of that would be:

```
<i class="icon-volume-off"></i>
```

And the following CSS:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
display: inline-block;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
margin-top: 1px;
line-height: 14px;
vertical-align: text-top;
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
background-position: 14px 14px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

.icon-volume-off {
    background-position: -360px -24px;
}
```